# I need to detect screen on or user present on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, widget, broadcast

I am developing a widget and I need to detect a screen on or user present intent in order to update the widget when the screen is switched on.

I have checked similar questions and answers on stack overflow and came to the conclusion that registering a service that will listen to SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF intents is not really a good solution since the service will be kept active all the time.

A possible solution is to detect screen on using the USER_PRESENT intent (which can be registered in the manifest and delivered to the widget, hence no need to keep a service in memory) and then update the widget as necessary. You can also register the screen on/off service on USER_PRESENT to handle the SCREEN_OFF intent and unregister it on screen off).

The problem is that, from previous experience, the USER_PRESENT intent is not always broadcasted. There are cases where the user does not have any screen lock defined (i.e., he selects the swipe method) and in such cases, the USER_PRESENT intent is not broadcasted.

Is there a way to make sure that the USER_PRESENT intent is broadcasted on all devices? If not, is there another way to detect when the screen turns on?

Comment: I was also looking for the same, but didn't find any solution so i chose to create a service and register broadcast receiver for `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` and `SCREEN_ON` and `SCREEN_OFF`.

Comment: That is what I do at the moment, but for a widget, it looks like this is not a good practice in the sense that the service stays in memory all the time. I am not sure if this can also be an additional reason for the system to kill the widget process in order to reclaim memory. Any more thoughts on this?